# documents.isEmpty boolean result not being received

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a phone number login view using Swift UI. It is successful at signing in existing users and fetching their profiles, but I'm having trouble displaying the signup flow for new users.

Currently, my function checks the database for profiles with a number equal to the one provided in the login. If there are no documents with that number it should trigger the signup view to show. Below is the code that makes that check

This if the function that checks if the document list is empty

```
func checkUser(phNo: String, completion: @escaping BooleanCompletionHandler) {
 
    db.collection(FIRCollections.Profiles.rawValue).whereField("phoneNumber", isEqualTo: phNo).getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
        
        let documents = snapshot.documents
        
        if documents.isEmpty {
            completion(false)
            print("documents are empty")
            return
        }
        
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

This function should fetch the result of if it was empty, and then toggle the showInfoView (but it doesn't)

```
func loginWithOTP(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    FirebaseService.shared.checkUser(phNo: phNo) { empty in
        
        if empty {
            print("otpverificationview empty confirmed")
            showInfoView = true
            return
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the "if empty" is not understood.

Comment: 'It seems that the "if empty" is not understood.' Can you clarify what you mean with that? Is there an error message?

Comment: can you show the code for `BooleanCompletionHandler`. Note that it seems to me that the completion result is back to front, in `if documents.isEmpty {...}` you should return `true`, else `false`.

Comment: Change `if empty {` to `if empty == true {` and `if documents.isEmpty { completion(false)` to `if documents.isEmpty == true { completion(true)` as you want the  `showInfoView` to happen if and only if no documents were found (empty == true). As a side note - this technique of checking phone numbers would mean all phone numbers would have to be stored in the clear, with no security, meaning anyone could download the entire list of phone numbers. Not sure if that really matters but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `isEmpty` on the snapshot itself, which was made for this use case. Also, you have some loose ends that you should tie up regarding control flow and error handling.

Notice in the `doesUserExist` function, by declaring the name of the Boolean in the function's signature (`completion: @escaping (_ userDoesExist: Bool?) -> Void`), Xcode will autocomplete it when it's called so there is zero ambiguity around what the completion handler is returning.

```
func doesUserExist(atPhoneNumber pn: String, completion: @escaping (_ userDoesExist: Bool?) -> Void) {
    db.collection(FIRCollections.Profiles.rawValue).whereField("phoneNumber", isEqualTo: pn).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error) // Always log errors while developing.
            }
            completion(nil) // Don't ever leave caller hanging.
            return
        }
        completion(!snapshot.isEmpty)
    }
}

func loginWithOTP(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    FirebaseService.shared.doesUserExist(atPhoneNumber: phNo) { (userDoesExist) in
        if let userDoesExist = userDoesExist {
            if userDoesExist {
                // Log in
            } else {
                // Sign up
            }
        } else {
            // Error! Don't log in or sign up, retry.
        }
    }
}
```

The following is an example of how you could further build out this flow, with the use of an enum.

```
enum AuthFlow {
    case signIn
    case signUp
    case retry
}

func loginWithOTP(completion: @escaping (_ nextStep: AuthFlow) -> Void) {
    FirebaseService.shared.doesUserExist(atPhoneNumber: phNo) { (userDoesExist) in
        if let userDoesExist = userDoesExist {
            if userDoesExist {
                completion(.signIn)
            } else {
                completion(.signUp)
            }
        } else {
            completion(.retry) // There was an error.
        }
    }
}

loginWithOTP { (nextStep) in
    switch nextStep {
    case .signIn:
        // ...
    case .signUp:
        // ...
    case .retry:
        // ...    
    }
}
```